# General arrays help needed (returning which arrays share a common value)

Tags: arrays, discord.js

I've built some code that parses commands, then pushes them to an array.

Every time a new command comes through, I'd like to compare to several other array that contain predetermined values, and output any possible array that matches it.

It looks a bit like this:

```
const collection1 = ['an apple', 'a banana', 'a cherry']
const collection2 = ['a cucumber', 'a pear', 'a banana']
const collection3 = ['a cabbage', 'a cherry', 'an apple']

let fruit
let array[]
case 'banana':
fruit = 'a banana'
break;

array.push(fruit)
```

I obviously have more than one 'case', just keeping it simple.
What I want to do, is when the user does a command where the argument is 'banana' for example, it returns which arrays that 'banana' is contained in. In this case, collection1 and collection2.

I only started learning code about a couple days ago and my first project was this Discord bot - hopefully you guys can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to only use arrays including a specific argument.

```js
// make an array of the arrays
const arrays = [
  ['an apple', 'a banana', 'a cherry'],
  ['a cucumber', 'a pear', 'a banana'],
  ['a cabbage', 'a cherry', 'an apple']
];

// filter all arrays which doesn't have the element `'a banana'`
console.log(arrays.filter((arr) => arr.includes('a banana')))
```

Comment: Just one more thing, let's say the names of the arrays are important for later on (collection1 for example) - can I add some kind of label to the array so that I can return the 'name' of any array with a match?